# Programming Arduino With Python

Tags: arduino-ide, library, python

Im a beginner working with arduino.
Im little familliar with java syn and its not hard for me to do the work with ide ;but i know python better....is there any Lib that let you program Arduino with Python?

Comment: [This page on playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/CommonTopics/PyMite) lists a number of links on the subject. As a matter of fact, the first paragraph hints how you may use python on your pc to interact with an arduino over a serial connection.

Comment: This has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a page on interfacing Arduino with Python.

[Interface Arduino with Python](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Python)